# Can't resolve symbol 'thisActivity'

Tags: android

I'm a new android developer.  I'm trying to get my app to check permissions and I found this bit of code [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY);
```

The problem I'm having is that `thisActivity`is showing up with the error `"Can't resolve symbol 'thisActivity'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`thisActivity` means you have to provide the reference of your activity.

Actually, if you are in `MainActivity` then you have to give `MainActivity.this`

So, your code for activity will be:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY);
```

and your code for fragment will be:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY);
```

Answer (score 2):

thisActivity is nothing but the refrence of your current activity.

Call it like this,

In case of activity:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyActivity.this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY);
```

In case of fragment:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY);
```